# Reconstruction Loss Factor effect on Beta VAE performance

Tags: python, keras, loss-function, autoencoder

I have a doubt regarding the VAE loss weight factors. VAE loss components are the reconstruction loss and KL loss. In beta VAE, KL loss is multiplied with beta to adjust the KL loss weight. In regular VAE I came across a reconstruction loss factor/ loss factor multiplied with reconstruction loss to adjust its weight. Is this reconstruction loss factor used in beta VAE? Will it affect its performance?
I found a relevant question here [why reconstruction loss function multiplied by constant in VAE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68106133/why-reconstruction-loss-function-multiplied-by-constant-in-vae) But there is no answer.